# When and where exactly do I cast an int to enum when making an AJAX call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, enums

My web method receives an enum parameter. I know that from client side I can send an int and then cast it to enum. But I got no clue as to when or where I do this casting? Suppose I have the following server method:

```
[WebMethod]
 public static void MethodThatReceivesAnEnum(enum myEnum)
 { }
```

And here's the AJAX call:

```
function enumTest(){
var enumArgument=1;
$.ajax({        
    type: "POST",
    url: "Ajax.aspx/MethodThatReceivesAnEnum",
    data: JSON.stringify({ myEnum:enumArgument }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(){}});
}
```

Do I have to do something inside the JavaScript function or the server method, or in both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are passing `number (int) from javascript` you can receive `int` on server and convert that to your enum.

```
public static void MethodThatReceivesAnEnum(int myEnumValue)
{ 
    YourEnum foo = (YourEnum)myEnumValue;
}
```

enum has integer compatible type you can try sending value to it and check of you get the right object.

```
public static void MethodThatReceivesAnEnum(YourEnum myEnumValue)
{ 
      if(myEnumValue == YourEnum.SomeEquilantValue)
      {

      }
}
```

Comment: I could do that and maybe eventually will. I used to have that pattern before but then I started using enums for making my method more self descriptive and for clarity, because this was everyone's advice. So this is my only way?

Comment: Try passing value to type of your enum and check if you get it right? I have updated my answer with suggest.

Answer (score 0):

To my surprise sending just an int for an enum parameter worked just fine. So the serializer takes care of the casting on its own. I should have checked and then asked the question but I would never believe that this could be true.